# could someone gives some examples about TypeIdentifier?

Tags: java

The Java 13 [Java Language Specification section 3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) says

> A type identifier is an identifier that is not the character sequence var.

```
TypeIdentifier:
Identifier but not var
```

Examples of identifiers are:

```
String

i3

αρετη

MAX_VALUE

isLetterOrDigit
```

could someone gives some examples about TypeIdentifier?

Answer (score 0):

*type* basically means class or interface.

*type identifier* is the name of a class or interface.

You cannot name a class or interface `var`.

This is not valid

```
public class var {
}
```

But this is valid (because identifiers in java are case sensitive)

```
public class Var {
}
```

Another example of a valid type identifier is

```
public interface Comparator {
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know `var` is being used somewhere else by jdk itself, so it is tagged as `reserved word`, I just want to know where it is being used?

Answer (score 0):

Basically. a `<TypeIdentifier>` is any `<Identifier>` apart from `var`.

> I know `var` is being used somewhere else by jdk itself,

Yes.

> so it is tagged as reserved word,

The identifier `var` is NOT a keyword.  See [JLS 3.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9).

Support for `var` was only added recently (Java 9, I think) and it had to be done in a way that was minimally disruptive.  To achieve this, they reserved `var` as (just) a `<TypeIdentifier>`.  (You can still use `var` as the name of a field or variable, a method or a package.  Just not the name of a Java `class`, `interface` or `enum`.)

> I just want to know where it is being used?

The `var` reserved word is used in local variable declarations; see [JLS 14.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4).  For example:

```
var a = 1;
```

The type of `a` is inferred to be `int`.